How to use long strings of text in Excel formulas (longer than 255 characters)
I have this Excel formula, which I am using to add a long passage of text to an Email sender:
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&$C$2&"?subject=Feedback from your Project Presentation"&"&body="&$F$2,"Send Email")

My problem is that Excel seems to impose a character limit, so if the cell for my student's feedback contains a high character count, the formula fails and shows as #VALUE!
The text causing the problem in in cell &$F$2 in the formula shown above.
After testing, it does seem to be a character count issue, but I really need to use quite long strings of text for the emails.
Any ideas?
I tried to use a string in cell &$F$2 with a character count higher than 166 characters.
I expected the formula to not be rejected by Excel's error checking algorithm.

So build it across a few cells. send it as 2 or 3 phrases.

This probably needs VBA --> UDF --> research there is a solution in the forum.

Thank you folks
I have opted for the simpler solution- just import the sheet to Google Sheets where this is not an issue
